# Android: Eclipse won't open

Tags: java, android, eclipse, crash, heap-memory

I'm currently making an Android application using Eclipse, but I made a small change and all of a sudden Eclipse crashed.  Now, every time I open Eclipse it crashes after about 5 minutes of trying to load, giving me the following message: " could not be instantiated.  Java heap."  Eclipse does not display the code before the error appears.  Any thoughts?  Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try restarting the computer and try again!!

Answer (score 0):

Look at the eclipse.ini file in your eclipse folder. You might need to increase the heap size (the -Xmx parameter).

Answer (score 0):

you edit the eclipse.ini file for your Eclipse instance, so that it includes the following settings:

```
-vmargs -Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:PermSize=64m
```